# Solve the 'max size limit exceeded' warning for openzeppelin's governor contract wizard

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, compiler-optimization, openzeppelin

I generated a contract for governance based on the wizard provided by openzeppelin here: https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/#governor

I didn't change any values in the fields and tried compiling the contract in hardhat. But it throws the below warning:

```
Warning: Contract code size is 25663 bytes and exceeds 24576 bytes 
(a limit introduced in Spurious Dragon). This contract may not be deployable on Mainnet.
```

Kindly someone help me resolve this. I need to use the timelock feature along with other default base contracts for governance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve this Hardhat CompilerError? (Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70310087/how-do-i-resolve-this-hardhat-compilererror-stack-too-deep-when-compiling-inli)

Comment: @Yilmaz Unfortunately no, I tried with optimizer, it didn't work.

Comment: try to work on logic to reduce the size. other wise you either need to separete the logic and deploy two contracts or create a library and deploy the library for the pure functions